# get value of php dropdown with javascript

Tags: php

```
<?php

    $apart_infos_list = $this->d->get_list_apart_infos(); 

    $apart_infos  = array('' => 'Επιλέξτε κατηγορία');

    foreach ($apart_infos_list as $apart_info) {


          $apart_infos[$apart_info] = $apart_info;

      }      

     echo form_dropdown

      ('',$apart_infos,'','name="txt_apart_info" class="form-control"'); 

?>
```

Comment: Use Jquery, it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

get option value:

```
var e = document.getElementById(id_of_select);
if (e)
{
    $value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    ....
}
```